# Is it possible to use text formatting within a hidden value in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to set up text that is being generated in a hidden value and is going to be displayed via a label, can I set up that hidden value to include text formatting so when the hidden value is displayed in a label certain text will be bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text formatting is performed with Markdown, so it must be applied *after* any data that's being loaded has been injected into the question's text. I've used constructs like

`This appointment is: **#form/days_late** days late`

and they've worked correctly.

That would mean that what gets "formatted" is the text of the question after everything is loaded, so it shouldn't matter whether

`days_late = '**3**'` and you output `#case/days_late Days Late`

or

`days_late = '3'` and you output `**#case/days_late** Days Late`

since what ultimately gets formatted is the result:

`**3** Days Late`

Keep in mind that everywhere you output that label will include the markdown, so you might want to save two copies of the text (one formatted one not) depending on where it will be used.

**Edit**:

I just tried this and noticed that the form won't necessarily apply markdown by default unless it detects that you are trying to use it.

If you don't see **Turn Off Text Formatting** next to the question where you are displaying the value you can trigger markdown on a question by putting in something like

`**test**`

into the question text and then removing it, after which it should stay on until/unless disabled manually.

Answer (score 0):

Related to the above, I've found that to get formatting for complex statements from within the hidden value, where it's tough to add ** on their own, you can place character strings housing the desired formatting command, you can have your label print and format 'automatically', ie:

```
'**','Jane said on ', format-date(today(), '%e/%n/%y'), ':', '** '
```

displays

**Jane said on 6/3/17:**

...might need to fiddle with your spacing a bit, though: my first go ended with ': ', '**', which prevents the formatting from working. The formatting character string has to sit exactly next to the text you want to affect.